# How do I tell if a holiday has passed (every year)?

Tags: php, math, date

Say I want to make a website that checks if my birthday has passed, I could easily do

```
    <?php
if( strtotime("2012-10-21") < time() ){
    echo "Birthday has passed";
    } else {
        echo "Birthday hasn't passed";
    } 
?>
```

But that would only account for one year, not every year in the future.
Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
    if (strtotime("21 October")<time()) {
        echo "Birthday has passed";
    } else {
        echo "Birthday hasn't passed";
    } 
?>
```

Just passing **21 October** to `strtotime()` automatically returns the UNIX timestamp for the current year.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that it was that easy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `mktime`, just leave the year parameter blank to use the current year.

```
if (mktime(1, 1, 1, 10, 21) < time()) {
    ...
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Answer (score -1):

PHP Manual: [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php)

```
if(mktime(23, 59, 59, $birthdayDate, $birthdayMonth) < time())
{
    //Birthday has passed
}
```

Edit: I used 23, 59, 59, so that it won't say that the birthday has passed, while it still IS the birthday